# Legacy Portable Firefox to run legacy portable Java only and ignore local install of Java

Tags: windows-10, firefox, java, portable, browser-plugin

Sorry to post a question regarding legacy applications but we mutiple systems that require legacy browsers and Java.

I need Portable Firefox to run the Portable Java JRE version and not the Java JRE installed on the OS.

The reason is we have HP iLOs console screen via Java.

Operating System is **Windows 10 Enteprise version 21h2**

I have Java 8 JRE update 202 installed locally on the OS for othe applications.

The following posts help me get so far:

[How to run two browsers (Firefox) with Java plugins in Windows (7) having different versions (1.6 and 1.7)?](https://superuser.com/questions/717968/how-to-run-two-browsers-firefox-with-java-plugins-in-windows-7-having-differ)

https://portableapps.com/node/21946

Portable Firefox version 3.6.28 install location:

**C:\PortableApps\FirefoxPortablev3.6.28**

Portable Java JRE 6 Update 22 install location:

**C:\PortableApps\CommonFiles\Java**

Configuration changes made to Portable Firefox and Portable Java:

```
Moved to follwing files to temporary folder:

- npdeploytk.dll
- npjpi160_17.dll
- npoji610.dll
- npt.dll

From C:\PortableApps\CommonFiles\Java\bin\ 
To C:\PortableApps\CommonFiles\Java\bin\_backup

Moved the following file:

- npjp2.dll

From C:\PortableApps\CommonFiles\Java\bin\new_plugin\
To C:\PortableApps\CommonFiles\Java\bin\

Edited the file called "FirefoxPortable.ini" located in C:\PortableApps\FirefoxPortablev3.6.28  with following content:

[FirefoxPortable]
PluginsDirectory=..\CommonFiles\Java\bin
```

The below will prevent firefox portable from using the "MozillaPlugins" registry entry.

Open up a new tab in portable firefox and enter this into web address **about:config** and proceed further.

Then search and set the following plugin to FALSE

```
set plugin.scan.plid.all to FALSE
```

When I launch Firefox portable and in the addin I only see Java 6 plugins:

[image: Firefox Plugins]

When I launch the Java application on the portable version of Firefox it uses the Java 6 plugin BUT is using Java 8 JRE not Java 6 JRE:

[image: Java Console Information]

This causes the application to fail as it is not supported on Java 8 JRE update 202 but I can confirm if the PC only has Java 6 JRE update 22 the Java application functions fine.

For some reason Java 8 JRE update 202 is still being used.

Is it possible to force Firefox portable to run Java Portable JRE and not the local install of Java JRE?

**Update 1**

The below URL show it is possible to do a offline install on JPortable version 7:

https://ryanwintaraga.wordpress.com/2013/02/10/how-to-install-jportable-offline/

I don't know if this is progress but as I am on closed internet network I was installed JPortable on my personal PC and copying folder *CommonFiles\Java* and all subfolder within *Java* to the PC I have the issue with.

So I decided to try version jPortable_7_Update_13_online.paf and I downloaded the JRE file jre-7u13-windows-i586

I put both files in a folder (this allow offline installation) and went through the install process on my closed network PC and made the same file changes as above and re-tested on the browser.

The difference here is I get a warning stating my Java is out of date (which is a good sign as it is using portable Java JRE update 13 for the first time):

[image: Java Warning]

Then after selecting the option I get a pop window for my app and after some time the browser crashes (no warning or error messages before it):

[image: Java Applet]

Comment: If you truly want to isolate Firefox form the system, just run it in a virtual machine. You can run a Windows 10 VM on Windows 10, and distribute the VM file to each machine. That avoids the issues of different version of Java, and any other machine-specific idiosyncrasy -- each VM will be like all the others.

Comment: I agree this would be a good solution but then I have only have VMs Oracle Virtual box which would require me to install this on all PCs that require this - does this require additional IP or can it use the host system IP aswell? I could also define some "spare" PCs which the same configurations of this VM aswell but just seeing if it is possible to make it work with "Portable Firefox and Portable Java"

Comment: I didn't follow everything you tried, but there's the [MOZ_PLUGIN_PATH environment variable method](https://portableapps.com/comment/161425#comment-161425) which might be simpler. There are also some instructions [here](https://portableapps.com/comment/138122#comment-138122) which you might verify against what you did.